# Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY in C#

Tags: c#

Can i have a equivalent o generate a Java Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [`double.PositiveInfinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity.aspx)? (aka `System.Double.PositiveInfinity`). The are similar values for negative infinity, NaN, epsilon (the smallest positive double) and min/max values.

It's a constant in the `double` struct. If that doesn't do what you want it to, please clarify.

Note that to *test* for infinity, you can use [`double.IsPositiveInfinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.ispositiveinfinity.aspx) (and `IsNegativeInfinity`, and just `IsInfinity`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Double.PositiveInfinity` constant. Example:

```
double huge = Double.PositiveInfinity;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [`Double.PositiveInfinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity.aspx).